# How to write 2 statements that differ just by Operator type in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, coding-style, operators

I have the following code sample, where the only difference between the 2 parts of the If statement is the less than/greater than operators.

Is there a better way to write this? Could almost do with being able to define an Operator variable.

```
        If myVar = true Then

            Do While (X < Y)
                'call Method A
                'the values of X and Y will change within this loop
            Loop

        Else

            Do While (X > Y)
                'call Method A
                'the values of X and Y will change within this loop
            Loop

        End If
```

thanks

Comment: Other than the number of lines of source code what you have is probably the fastest.  iif and if() are notoriously slow.

Comment: @dbasnett - Are you referring to the If() operator or the If() function?  If the former, can you provide a link that details any performance problems with the If() operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ternary conditional operator, `If`, as of VB 2008:

```
Do While (If(myVar, X < Y, X > Y)))
    'call Method A
Loop
```

However, this will check `myVar` on every iteration instead of just once, which is bad for performance.

Comment: Thanks - I don't think performance is an issue too much here as the values of X and Y are always less than 10! 
This compiles in VS 2008, against .NET 2.0, but not in VS 2005 against .NET 2.0 - do you know why?

Comment: In VS2005 you have to use the Iif operator instead (and cast it to CInt). You can see a sample of that in my answer.

Comment: @Richard: I'd recommend @ho's answer over mine. It's a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim from As Integer = CInt(iif(myVar, x, y))
Dim until As Integer = CInt(iif(myVar, y, x))

While from < until
    'call Method A
End While
```

Or if 2008 or newer, as Samir says, use the ternary conditional operator to avoid the CInt casts.

Comment: This answer's pretty good—it avoids the potential performance problem and is still very readable.

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately that won't work in this case as the values of X and Y will change within the While loop (sorry, forgot to mention that first time round!)

Comment: @Richard You can set "from" and "until" in the loop as well

Comment: @Joel - yes I realise that, but that would mean the extra overhead of the iif statements within the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegate:

```
Public Function LessThan(Of T As IComparable)(ByVal A As T, ByVal B As T) As Boolean
    Return A.CompareTo(B) < 0
End Function

Public Function GreaterThan(Of T AS IComparable)(ByVal A As T, ByVal B As T)  As Boolean
    Return A.CompareTo(B) > 0
End Function
```

---

```
Dim comparer As Func(Of Integer,Integer,Boolean) = AddressOf GreaterThan(Of Integer)
If myVar Then comparer = AddressOf LessThan(Of Integer)

Do While comparer(X,Y)
    ''#call Method A
    ''#the values of X and Y will change within this loop
Loop
```

---

Of course, that needs VS2008.  For more fun:

```
Do While CBool(Y.CompareTo(Y) * -1) = myVar
    ''#...
End While
```

Comment: Interesting answer indeed! I hadn't seen the Func Delegate before, but looks like I'll have to wait until my app moves on from .NET 2.0.
I'll bear this in mind for later though thanks

Comment: @Richard - you can define the Func delegate for yourself in .Net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While ((myVar And X < Y) Or (Not myVar And X > Y))
    ' call Method A
Loop
```